# predicting outcome with a model in R

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am trying to do a simple prediction, using linear regression
I have a data.frame where some of the items are missing price (and therefor noted NA).
This apperantely doesn't work:

```
#Simple LR
fit <- lm(Price ~ Par1 + Par2 + Par3, data=combi[!is.na(combi$Price),])
Prediction <- predict(fit,  data=combi[is.na(combi$Price),]), OOB=TRUE, type = "response")
```

What should I put instead of `data=combi[is.na(combi$Price),])` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `data` to `newdata`. Look at `?predict.lm` to see what arguments `predict` can take. Additional arguments are ignored. So in your case `data` (and `OOB`) is ignored and the default is to return predictions on the training data.

```
Prediction <- predict(fit, newdata = combi[is.na(combi$Price),])

identical(predict(fit), predict(fit, data = combi[is.na(combi$Price),]))
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: You don't have to explicitly exclude `NA` in the original fit either, the default `na.action` is to `na.omit`, which omits rows with any `NA` values. Also, note that there is a `predict(...)` method for just about every modelling package in R, and some of them do take the `type=...' argument. `predict.glm(...)` is an important case in point, where you would indeed need to specify `type="response"`.